# Fetch: I see the response in the DevTools but Fetch still gives me an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" issue for GET

Tags: javascript, get, cors, fetch-api

So I have an issue regarding `fetch` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I try to fetch some site like this:

```
fetch('https://localhost/.../api/json')
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => console.log("data:", data))
    .catch(err => console.log("err: ", err));
```

So in the Chrome Network tab, I see that apparently there was no issue.
However, in JavaScript code, I get `CORS` issues. How is that even possible? See:

[image]

I tried adding `mode: 'cors'` it does not help. I tried adding `mode: 'no-cors'` yes it goes through but I can’t read the answer in this case I get `Unexpected end of input` and the `'blob'` variable is empty anyway.

If I do the same GET request without any options or headers using `Postman` or `Curl` it works like a charm and I get my response.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance

Edit: Since it is working on `Postmann` and `Curl` and since I can see the response in the Chrome Debugger, I don’t think that it is a duplicate of another question where the request clearly goes to an external URL that does not allow to be accessed from somewhere else. Right?

Edit2: Could it potentially have to do that the address: `https://localhost` is self-signed and thus has no valid certificate? In `curl` I had to add `--insecure` flag.

Comment: *"So what can I do?"* There's nothing you *can* do. The **server** has to authorize the request, otherwise the browser will prevent your code from seeing the response. That's how the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please explain why it is working in `Postman` or `Curl` then and why I can see the answer in the browser debugger? Does not seem right to me & does not seem like a duplicate.

Comment: That's covered in the answers to the linked question, please do take the time to read them. Note the bit in my comment above *"...otherwise **the browser** will prevent your code from seeing the response..."* Postman and Curl and such aren't browsers. The SOP is a browser-specific thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wonder where the protection is when I can still see the answer in the browser network tab (see picture). Shouldn’t it return you some kind of error instead? Where is the benefit if you can still see the response but not in JS?

Comment: So if what you say is true (which is not very clear to me), then there is actually a possibility for get requests at least: setup another api server that uses `curl` under the hood. Then you would start contacting api2 which uses curl on api1 and passes the data from api1 back to the client.
I’ll try it on monday. That will work 90% sure. Then I don’t understand why the browser prevents the direct get in the first place when I can bypassed it anyway.

Comment: It would be clear to you if you read the SOP Wikipedia article linked above, particularly [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Security_Applications). I've also added a second dupetarget above, and [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/08/28/same-origin-policy-part-1-no-peeking/) may help.

Comment: In short: The SOP applies only in browsers because the security threat is only present in browsers: If you're logged into your banking site, for instance, then open a tab and to go a malicious site, without the SOP the malicious site could request and read information from your bank -- *using your authenticated session*. You probably don't want every site you visit to be able to do that. Or read your Facebook private messages. Or your private email. Or post spam on SO using your account. All of which is possible without the SOP.

Comment: Well, thanks for taking the time to clarify!! :)
By the way, the curl bypass I mentioned is working. Greets

Comment: Yup, that's the usual way around it: Involve a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by T.J. Crowder, this is **impossible to do in the browser**. See related resources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Security_Applications
- https://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/08/28/same-origin-policy-part-1-no-peeking/

But, do not despair! There is a **workaround**:

## cURL Server Workaround:

We are going to use a node server calling `cURL` to bypass the restriction:

You’ll need nodejs with npm.

- Do `npm init` and `npm i -S express`
- Add an `api.js` file. With following code:

```js
    const https = require("https");
    const express = require('express');

    const app = express();

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        const exec = require('child_process').exec;

        exec('curl ' + req.query.url + ' --insecure', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
          console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
          console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

          res.json(stdout);

          if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
          }
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000, function () { console.log('listening on port 3000!'); });
```

- Run the server via `node api.js`
- Now in your code you can make a request to `localhost:3000` adding the url you want to make the `get` request to in the query parameters. Example:

```js
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/?url=https://HOST/.../api/json')
      .then(blob => blob.json())
      .then(data => console.log("data:", data))
      .catch(err => console.log("err: ", err));
```

- The requerst is now working as expected. Enjoy.